# Navigate into 2 pages in the same test

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I'm very new in Javascript and Cypress so pardon me if it's something very simple.

What I would like to do is to navigate into 2 pages inside one test.
My test.cy.js file has this code:

```
describe('Sitop Manager Login Page', () => {
  it('opens login page, fill the form and clicks submit', () => {
    cy.visit('/login')
    cy.get('input[name="username"]').type('admin')
    cy.get('input[name="password"]').type('admin')
    cy.contains('Login').click()
  })
  it('Open devices page', () => {
    cy.visit('/devices')
    cy.wait(500)
    cy.get('ix-menu ix-menu-item[tab-icon=cogwheel]').click() //css selector
  })
})
```

The issue is that when it finishes the /login page, then it reloads to login page again so the /devices page cannot be tested. In my cypress.config.js file i have setted the baseUrl

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000', //Baseurl to be used in all accross the testing classes
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Is the test runner reloading the login page, or is the server redirecting the browser from the `/devices` route to the `/login` route?  Is `/devices` a "login required" route?

Comment: Sorry @MattMorgan i am not quite sure what to check here. I am very new. If this helps, i put      `cy.visit('/devices')` inside the first `it`  and it works normally. So after it changes `it`  it returns to /login page

Comment: Forget about the testing scenario for a moment.  When you visit the site normally, do you have to be logged in to visit `/devices`?  If you try to visit it while not logged in, do you get redirected to `/login`?  If that's the case, then you need to enter the logged in state before you can test `/devices`.

Comment: If you have a case that works, then posting that code example would be useful information for anyone trying to help...I suggest adding it!

Comment: @MattMorgan Ah yes it needs to be logged in to be able to access /devices . How do i enter this logged in state?

Comment: By logging in?  I think you already have your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/devices` is a "login required" route, then the first step in any test that accesses it must be to log in.  So you will always need to visit `/login` first, go through the login workflow, then you can visit `/devices`.

```
  it('Open devices page', () => {
    cy.visit('/login')
    cy.get('input[name="username"]').type('admin')
    cy.get('input[name="password"]').type('admin')
    cy.contains('Login').click()
    cy.wait(500)
    cy.visit('/devices')
    cy.get('ix-menu ix-menu-item[tab-icon=cogwheel]').click() //css selector

  })
```

The `wait` after logging in and before visiting `/devices` may not be necessary, depending on the default timeout settings for your testing environment.

As @jjhelguero mentioned in the comments, you can also intercept a network request (perhaps to your login endpoint) and wait for it to return successfully as an alternative to the `wait`.  `get` will [retry](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Assertions-Icon-namequestion-circle), but could timeout: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept

There are things you can do to avoid needing to actually log in, like setting a session cookie, but probably you want to emulate the actual user workflow in your tests.

Comment: Oh i see... Is there any way to just have login function somewhere and just call it with 1 line? Because in the future i will need to create more tests to test other pages than /devices

Comment: That's a different question!  I suggest asking that separately.

Comment: I'm sure there is a request you can spy on before your login click and then wait on that instead of the arbitrary wait.